# bash compare two tar.gz

Tags: bash, compare, tar, gzip

I need to compare two archives tar.gz, without unpacking them, listing file names from the 1st arch that aren't in the 2nd arch.

I've tried a few ways but every one has failed. I'm new to bash.

Answer (score 6):

```
comm -23 <(tar -tzf 1.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tzf 2.tar.gz | sort)
```

Comment: Splendid *THUMBS UP* So I've learn and started to read ss64, but still I was unable to apply this for my problem. My goal is to write out files that are in 1st arch and not in 2nd but when a subdirectory is missing, then it does not write any file or directory from the subdirectory, only name of the subdirectory. (EX. 1=(b/c.txt;b/e/a.txt;b/e/c),2=(b/c.txt;a) result=(b/e/)). I also tried diff but it didn't even work when arch1==arch2.

Comment: Can you please explain the output? How to infer the list. I have a pair of big tar files to compare.